# IIS7 adding part to application URL

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a problem deploying an application in IIS. Basically, I have a website with an ASP.NET application. When I try to access to my site: myDomain.com/myApp/myPage, the URL transforms to become: myDomain.com/myApp/ myApp/myPage and I get a error 404. If I remove the myApp part that was added, it works fine, I have access to my page.

I'm new with IIS, I don't know why the application's name is added in the URL. Is it IIS doing that for a reason or is it something known to do that in the web.config?

Comment: can you post a picture of who you have IIS setup? it sounds like you have set the site up under another default website, and not a website in itself. Always setup a website at root and assign a valid port, avoid nesting sites unless you really have to (i.e. you want multiple sites served on port 80).

Comment: [iis config](http://i.imgur.com/5EFSDwJ.png) i have multiple website all binding to the same port, They are all direct website and the one that i'm working on is the fisrt with app in it @Macb